# Why the UIView get transparent at the end of an animnation in Unity?

Tags: objective-c, animation, unity-game-engine

I add an UIView to the window. And act an animnation from itself size to full screen . But at the end of the screen , it has some transparent splash appear. I can see the interface of Unity , not my uiview?

My code is like this:

```
UIView * view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:....]; // a animnation start view rect
CGRect rect = [view convertRect:view.bounds toViewarentView];
UIView * parentView = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] subviews]     objectAtIndex:0];
UIView *picv = [[PicView alloc] initWithFrame: parentView.bounds];
picv.frame = rect;
[parentView addSubviewicv];

[UIView animateWithDuration:2.3 animations:^{
picv.frame = parentView.bounds;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
[picv setFullImage]; 
}];
```

Does anyone can give me some tips?

Comment: The unity tag is used for Microsoft Unity. Please don't misuse it.